# only 8gb storage on kali linux live on 64gb flash drive

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, operating-systems, iso-image, kali-linux

I just got kali Linux Live and put it on my 64Gb flash drive. To install updates these take up to 6Gb of storage. I need your help to solve why I have about only 8Gb of storage on a 64Gb flash drive.

Another problem

When I shutdown my computer and opened Kali Linux live everything I installed got deleted.

Comment: Could you add to the question the output of `lsblk` ?

Comment: You have a live image with no persistent storage. Most live distributions are using a ramdrive to store changes to the system. Check the Kali documentation if they have a way to save the changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
why I have about only 8Gb of storage on a 64Gb flash drive
```

You simply created bootable USB by cloning from an iso file onto the device of a USB pendrive.
To use complete drives as bootable USB, you will have to extract files from an iso file into a FAT32 file system in a partition in a USB pendrive

On windows : use [rufs](https://www.rufs.se/)

[image]

On linux : use [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/)

Note - the above applications work by copying all iso files to drive and then make it bootable and thus using comple USB drive

```
When I shutdown my computer and opened Kali Linux live everything I installed got deleted.
```

It's not a problem but a expected behaviour ir Live USB. Use persistent live USB for that.

**Adding Persistence to a Linux "Live" USB Drive**

On windows : use [rufs](https://www.rufs.se/)

[image]

On linux :

### From - [kali-linux-live-usb-persistence](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence/)

Assuming

- have root access (to create the usb)
- your USB drive is /dev/sdb
- your USB drive has a capacity of at least 8GB — the Kali Linux image
  takes over 3GB, and for this guide, we'll be creating a new partition
  of about 4GB to store our persistent data in.

In this example, we'll create a new partition to store our persistent data into, starting right above the second Kali Live partition and ending at 7GB, put an ext3 file system onto it, and create a persistence.conf file on the new partition.

First, begin by imaging the latest Kali Linux ISO to your USB drive using

- dd with a status indicator

> ```
> dd if=kali-linux-2020.3-live-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M status=progress
> ```

- pv

> ```
>  dd if=kali-linux-2020.3-live-amd64.iso | pv -s 2.8G | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=4M
> ```

We're going to assume that the two partitions created by the imaging are /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb2. This can be verified with the command `fdisk -l`.

Create and format an additional partition on the USB drive. First, let's create the new partition in the empty space above our Kali Live partitions. We have to do this from the command line as gparted will read the imaged ISO as a large block. The following command will, as a short explanation, shrink that block to only be the Kali Live partition.

```
end=7GiB

read start _ < <(du -bcm kali-linux-2020.3-live-amd64.iso | tail -1); echo $start

parted /dev/sdb mkpart primary ${start}MiB $end
```

The parted command may advise you that it can't use the exact start values you specified; if so, accept the suggested value instead. If advised that the partition isn't placed at an optimal location, "ignore" it. When parted completes, the new partition should have been created at /dev/sdb3; again, this can be verified with the command `fdisk -l`.

Next, create an ext3 file system in the partition and label it persistence.

```
mkfs.ext3 -L persistence /dev/sdb3

e2label /dev/sdb3 persistence
```

Create a mount point, mount the new partition there, and then create the configuration file to enable persistence. Finally, unmount the partition.

```
mkdir -p /mnt/my_usb
mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/my_usb
echo "/ union" > /mnt/my_usb/persistence.conf
umount /dev/sdb3
```

---

Some more info :

From - [persistent-usb-live-session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal)

> A persistent Live USB is essentially a copy of the installation DVD.
> The files in the original ISO remains as is in a read only file
> system. All the Updates and extra software you install are saved in
> the space designated for keeping the changes.

From - [persistent Live USB](https://askubuntu.com/a/1100352/1095264)

> The files in the original ISO remains as is in a read only file
> system. All the Updates and extra software you install are saved in
> the space designated for keeping the changes.
>
> In persistent installation the old one stays as is, the newer version
> is located in the persistent virtual disk (within the USB) taking up
> extra space